# showing thumbnails of remote raw files

Tags: pantheon-files

I'm searching for a solution to show thumbnails of photo raw data (~15 MB in size) from samba sever (remote files on a NAS) in pantheon files . I guess the issue is the file size. How can I edit the standard settings? It works fine with JPEG files.

I installed caja to test NEF thumbnails and it workes like a charme only by editing the settings to "show all" and "files smaller than 100 MB only".

Do I have to change something in /etc/xdg/tumbler/tumbler.rc?

```
# RAW image files using libopenraw
[RawThumbnailer]
Disabled=false
Priority=1
Locations=
MaxFileSize=0
```

Tumbler and tumbler-plugins-extra are installed.

Comment: You could try the fix here: https://gist.github.com/h4cc/13450db3d4a7457f9b38. Note that you may have to clear the thumbnail cache (~/.thumbnails) to force Files/tumbler to regenerate a thumbnail for a file that has already failed to thumbnail.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it. My current observation is that the raw files are being loaded into Caja. As soon as they are loaded there, i.e. the thumbnails are displayed, the same thumbnails are being displayed in pantheon files, too.